# If $A$ and $B$ are independent events of a sample space associated with a random experiment, show that $A$ and $B^c$ are also independent events.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are independent events of a sample space associated with a random experiment, $A$ and $B^c$ are also independent events.

My attempt is to use the condition probability $P(A|B)$ or the probability of event $A$ given that event $B$ has occured:

$$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A | B^c)P(B^c) = [1-P(A^c | B^c)]P(B^c)$$
$$=P(B^c)-P(B^c)P(A^c | B^c)$$

How could I continue this if I want to show that $P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)P(B^c)$?

Comment: Note that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$ by law of total probability.  Knowing that $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have then be rearranging $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times 1 - P(A)\times P(B)$.  Factoring lets the result follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use $P(B^c|A)$ instead of $P(A|B^c)$. So, your first equation becomes:
$$P(A \cap B^c) = P(B^c|A)P(A) = (1-P(B|A))P(A)$$Since $A$ and $B$ are independent events, what is $P(B|A)$?For independent events $X$ and $Y$, what is $P(X \cap Y)$? Can you take it from here?